# Discord.js error message on deleting Bot message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So basically I am lately always getting the following Error when I delete a message that my Bot sends. The message is not being used by the Bot anymore, but for some reason, it always crashes after deletion.

```
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Disc-Bots\discordBot_SGE-EventManager\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154
      throw new DiscordAPIError(request.path, data, request.method, res.status);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Disc-Bots\discordBot_SGE-EventManager\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Disc-Bots\discordBot_SGE-EventManager\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
    at async MessageManager.delete (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Disc-Bots\discordBot_SGE-EventManager\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\MessageManager.js:126:5) {
  method: 'delete',
  path: '/channels/822433440103268362/messages/822874032402726952',
  code: 10008,
  httpStatus: 404
}
```

Here is the Code for the command where it always has the problems with:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'hostit',
    aliases: ['hostits'],
    execute: async function (message, args, client) {
        message.delete()
        switch(args[0]){
            
            //Patrol Command
            case "patrol":
                let title = "[SGE] Event - Patrol"
                let description = `A new patrol has been hosted by ${message.author}!\nCome down to the patrol and get some activity!\n\nhttps://placeholder.com`
                
                // Notification that it was sent
                const confirmationembled = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('GREEN')
                .setDescription('Success! Patrol hosted in <#'+eventChannelId+'>!')
                message.channel.send(confirmationembled)
                message.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
        
                    // Actual event channel
                    const patrolembed = new MessageEmbed()
                    patrolembed.setColor('GREEN')
                    .setTitle(title)
                    .setDescription(description)
                    
                    //Log Event Creation
                    client.channels.cache.get(config.logChannelId).send("[**<@"+message.author+">**] hosted a patrol at "+new Date().toLocaleString())

                    // Send Event to Eventchannel
                    const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(config.eventChannelId)
                    if (!channel) {
                        const { owner } = await client.fetchApplication()
                        return owner.send("Channel does not exist, please check your config.json file.")
                    }
                    channel.send(patrolembed)
                    channel.send('NoGhostPing!').then(msg => msg.delete())
                break;
            
            // Not an host command  
            default:
                message.reply("This Command does not exists, please use -help to see all commands!").then(msg => { msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })})
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

As you see I never actually want to edit any of my messages, that I send out with the bot.

Comment: Can you please add your code?

Comment: You should probably post your code, check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you delete the message twice. The first time you delete it right at the start of the command, the second time in the `case: "patrol"`. So I would recommend you to only delete it in the switch/case, because in the `default` branch you want to reply to the message. This will be your code then (I just removed one line):

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'hostit',
    aliases: ['hostits'],
    execute: async function (message, args, client) {
        switch(args[0]){
            
            //Patrol Command
            case "patrol":
                let title = "[SGE] Event - Patrol"
                let description = `A new patrol has been hosted by ${message.author}!\nCome down to the patrol and get some activity!\n\nhttps://placeholder.com`
                
                // Notification that it was sent
                const confirmationembled = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('GREEN')
                .setDescription('Success! Patrol hosted in <#'+eventChannelId+'>!')
                message.channel.send(confirmationembled)
                message.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
        
                    // Actual event channel
                    const patrolembed = new MessageEmbed()
                    patrolembed.setColor('GREEN')
                    .setTitle(title)
                    .setDescription(description)
                    
                    //Log Event Creation
                    client.channels.cache.get(config.logChannelId).send("[**<@"+message.author+">**] hosted a patrol at "+new Date().toLocaleString())

                    // Send Event to Eventchannel
                    const channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(config.eventChannelId)
                    if (!channel) {
                        const { owner } = await client.fetchApplication()
                        return owner.send("Channel does not exist, please check your config.json file.")
                    }
                    channel.send(patrolembed)
                    channel.send('NoGhostPing!').then(msg => msg.delete())
                break;
            
            // Not an host command  
            default:
                message.reply("This Command does not exists, please use -help to see all commands!").then(msg => { msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })})
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, that somehow I didn't saw it.
Thanks a lot!